# Inconveniente con go_router en flutter: no redirige al home, se queda en el login

Tags: flutter, dart, programación-móvil

Estoy utilizando riverpod como gestor de estados y go_router para la administración de rutas.
En este punto tengo inconvenientes al declarar las redirecciones de las rutas dependiendo el estado de la autenticación, es decir: quiero que si el usuario NO está autenticado pueda acceder a todas las rutas excepto a una '/product/', y si SÍ está autenticado pueda acceder a todas. El problema que presento es que al estar en la pantalla de login y colocar las credenciales correctas no me redirige a la página del home, sino que se queda en el login.

Comparto el código para ser más específico.

```dart
import 'package:app_flutter_imm/presentation/providers/auth_provider/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:app_flutter_imm/presentation/screens/instructivo_all_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

import '../../presentation/screens/screens.dart';
import 'app_router_notifier.dart';

final goRouterProvider = Provider((ref) {

  final goRouterNotifier = ref.read(goRouterNotifierProvider);
  return GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/checking',
    refreshListenable: goRouterNotifier,
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
          path: '/',
          name: HomeScreen.name,
          builder: (context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: 'speciality/:id',
              name: SpecialityScreen.name,
              builder: (context, state) {
                final specialId = state.pathParameters['id'] ?? 'no-id';
                return SpecialityScreen(specialId: specialId);
              },
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: 'posts/:id',
              name: PostScreen.name,
              builder: (context, state) {
                final postId = state.pathParameters['id'] ?? 'no-id';
                return PostScreen(postId: postId);
              },
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: 'services/:id',
              name: ServicesScreen.name,
              builder: (context, state) {
                final serviceId = state.pathParameters['id'] ?? 'no-id';
                return ServicesScreen(serviceId: serviceId);
              },
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: 'product/:id',
              name: ProductScreen.name,
              builder: (context, state) {
                final productId = state.pathParameters['id'] ?? 'no-id';
                return ProductScreen(productId: productId);
              },
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: 'doctorgineco/:id',
              name: DoctorGinecoDetailScreen.name,
              builder: (context, state) {
                final doctorId = state.pathParameters['id'] ?? 'no-id';
                return DoctorGinecoDetailScreen(doctorId: doctorId);
              },
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: 'doctorendo/:id',
              name: DoctorEndoDetailScreen.name,
              builder: (context, state) {
                final doctorId = state.pathParameters['id'] ?? 'no-id';
                return DoctorEndoDetailScreen(doctorId: doctorId);
              },
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: 'instructivo/:id',
              name: InstructivoDetailScreen.name,
              builder: (context, state) {
                final instructiveId = state.pathParameters['id'] ?? 'no-id';
                return InstructivoDetailScreen(instructiveId: instructiveId);
              },
            ),
          ]),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/checking',
        name: CheckAuthStatusScreen.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const CheckAuthStatusScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/postsAll',
        name: PostAllScreen.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const PostAllScreen(
          post: [],
        ),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/docginecolist',
        name: DoctorsGinecoScreen.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const DoctorsGinecoScreen(
          docgineco: [],
        ),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/docendolist',
        name: DoctorsEndoScreen.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const DoctorsEndoScreen(
          docendo: [],
        ),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/servicesAll',
        name: ServicesAllScreen.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const ServicesAllScreen(
          service: [],
        ),
      ),

      GoRoute(
        path: '/productsAll',
        name: ProductsAllScreen.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const ProductsAllScreen(
          producto: [],
        ),
      ),

      GoRoute(
        path: '/instructivoAll',
        name: InstructivoAllScreen.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const InstructivoAllScreen(
          instructi: [],
        ),
      ),

      GoRoute(
        path: '/contact',
        name: ContactScreen.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const ContactScreen(),
      ),

      GoRoute(
        path: '/loginScreen',
        name: LoginScreen.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const LoginScreen(),
      ),
    ],

    redirect: (contex, state) {

      final isGoingTo = state.matchedLocation;
      final authStatus = goRouterNotifier.authStatus;

      if (isGoingTo == '/checking' && authStatus == AuthStatus.checking) return null;

      if (authStatus == AuthStatus.notAuthenticated) {
        if (
          isGoingTo == '/' ||
          isGoingTo == '/loginScreen' ||
          isGoingTo == '/postsAll' ||
          isGoingTo == '/docginecolist' ||
          isGoingTo == '/docendolist' ||
          isGoingTo == '/servicesAll' ||
          isGoingTo == '/productsAll' ||
          isGoingTo == '/instructivoAll' ||
          isGoingTo.contains('/posts/')  ||
          isGoingTo.contains('/speciality/')  ||
          isGoingTo.contains('/services/')  ||
         // isGoingTo.contains('/product/')  ||
          isGoingTo.contains('/doctorgineco/')  ||
          isGoingTo.contains('/doctorendo/')  ||
          isGoingTo.contains('/instructivo/')  ||
          isGoingTo == '/contact' ) return null;

        return '/loginScreen';
      }

      if (authStatus == AuthStatus.authenticated) {
        if (isGoingTo == '/loginScreen' || isGoingTo == '/checking') return '/';
    return null;
        
      }
        return '/';

    }
  );
});
```

Código del appNotifier

```dart
import 'package:app_flutter_imm/presentation/providers/auth_provider/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';


final goRouterNotifierProvider = Provider((ref) {
  final authNotifier = ref.read( authProvider.notifier);
  return GoRouterNotifier(authNotifier);
});


class GoRouterNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {

  final AuthNotifier _authNotifier;

  AuthStatus _authStatus = AuthStatus.checking;

  GoRouterNotifier(this._authNotifier) {
    _authNotifier.addListener((state) {
      authStatus = state.authStatus;
    });
  }


  AuthStatus get authStatus => _authStatus;

  set authStatus( AuthStatus value ) {
    _authStatus = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Código del auth_provider (riverpod)

```dart
import 'package:app_flutter_imm/infrastructure/errors/auth_errors.dart';
import 'package:app_flutter_imm/infrastructure/repositories/auth_repository_impl.dart';
import 'package:app_flutter_imm/infrastructure/services/key_value_storage_service.dart';
import 'package:app_flutter_imm/infrastructure/services/key_value_storage_service_impl.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import '../../../domain/entities/user_entities.dart';
import '../../../domain/repositories/auth_repository.dart';


final authProvider = StateNotifierProvider<AuthNotifier,AuthState>((ref) {

  final authRepository = AuthRepositoryImpl();
  final keyValueStorageService = KeyValueStorageServicesImple();

  return AuthNotifier(
    authRepository: authRepository,
    keyValueStorageService: keyValueStorageService
  );
});


class AuthNotifier extends StateNotifier<AuthState> {

  final AuthRepository authRepository;
  final KeyValueStorageServices keyValueStorageService;

  AuthNotifier({
    required this.authRepository,
    required this.keyValueStorageService,
  }): super( AuthState() ) { 
    checkAuthStatus();
   }
  

  Future<void> loginUser( String email, String password ) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    try {
      final user = await authRepository.login(email, password);
      _setLoggedUser( user );

    } on CustomError catch (e) {
      logout( e.message );
    } catch (e){
      logout( 'Error no controlado' );
    }

  }

  void checkAuthStatus() async {
    final token = await keyValueStorageService.getValue<String>('token');
    if( token == null ) return logout();

    try {
      final user = await authRepository.checkAuthStatus(token);
      _setLoggedUser(user);

    } catch (e) {
      logout();
    }

  }

  void _setLoggedUser( User user ) async {
    
    await keyValueStorageService.setKeyValue('token', user.token);

    state = state.copyWith(
      user: user,
      authStatus: AuthStatus.authenticated,
      errorMessage: '',
    );
  }

  Future<void> logout([ String? errorMessage ]) async {
    
    await keyValueStorageService.removeKey('token');

    state = state.copyWith(
      authStatus: AuthStatus.notAuthenticated,
      user: null,
      errorMessage: errorMessage
    );
  }

}



enum AuthStatus { checking, authenticated, notAuthenticated }

class AuthState {

  final AuthStatus authStatus;
  final User? user;
  final String errorMessage;

  AuthState({
    this.authStatus = AuthStatus.checking, 
    this.user, 
    this.errorMessage = ''
  });

  AuthState copyWith({
    AuthStatus? authStatus,
    User? user,
    String? errorMessage,
  }) => AuthState(
    authStatus: authStatus ?? this.authStatus,
    user: user ?? this.user,
    errorMessage: errorMessage ?? this.errorMessage
  );

}
```

Código del loginScreen

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:app_flutter_imm/presentation/providers/auth_provider/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:app_flutter_imm/presentation/providers/login_provider/login_form_provider.dart';
import 'package:app_flutter_imm/presentation/widgets/widgets.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String name = 'loginScreen';
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF8F7F7),
        title: const Text('Inciar Seción')),
      body: const _LoginView(),
    );
  }
}

class _LoginView extends StatelessWidget {
  const _LoginView();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: const Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF8F7F7),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                FlutterLogo(size: 100),
                _LoginForm(),
                SizedBox(height: 20)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _LoginForm extends ConsumerWidget {
  const _LoginForm();

   void showSnackbar( BuildContext context, String message ) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text(message))
    );
    }  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {

    final loginForm = ref.watch(loginFormProvider);

    ref.listen(authProvider, (previous, next) {
      if ( next.errorMessage.isEmpty) return;
      showSnackbar( context, next.errorMessage);
     });


    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
      child: Column(
        children: [
     
          const SizedBox( height: 90 ),

           CustomTextFormField(
            label: 'Correo',
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            onChanged: ref.read(loginFormProvider.notifier).onEmailChange,
            errorMessage: loginForm.isFormPosted ?
               loginForm.email.errorMessage 
               : null,
          ),
          const SizedBox( height: 30 ),

          CustomTextFormField(
            label: 'Contraseña',
            obscureText: true,
            onChanged: ref.read(loginFormProvider.notifier).onPasswordChanged,
            onFieldSubmitted: (_) => ref.read(loginFormProvider.notifier).onFormSubmit(),
            errorMessage: loginForm.isFormPosted ?
               loginForm.password.errorMessage 
               : null,
          ),
    
          const SizedBox( height: 30 ),

           SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 50,
            child: FilledButton.tonalIcon(
            onPressed: () {
              ref.read(loginFormProvider.notifier).onFormSubmit();
             },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.login_sharp),
            label: const Text('Ingresar'),
          ),
          ),

      
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text('¿No tienes cuenta?'),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: ()=> context.push('/'), 
                child: const Text('Contactanos')
              )
            ],
          ),

   
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  
  }
```

Comment: Añade el código de la pantalla de inicio de sesión, para verificar como estas ingresando, además si te sale algún error también agrégalo.

Comment: Ok, ya agregue el codigo del loginScreen a la pregunta, en realidad no percibo ningún error. pero te comento que si el "initialLocation" es /loginScreen si funciona la redirección de la ruta al home, pero no es lo que requiero, ya que  necesito que sea el home la primera pantalla. muchas gracias